# Permission denied - xampp osx

Tags: php

Почему то не хочет загружать файл, пишет что нету прав хотя они выставлены.

Код:

```
    <?php

    $uploaddir = dirname(getcwd()).'/img/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "The file ". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
            "Status" => "OK"
        ]);
    } else {
         echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
            "Status" => "Error"
        ]);
    }

?>
```

Вывод:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/img/123.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php on line 6

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpWdbwtd' to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/img/123.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php on line 6
{"Message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.","Status":"Error"}
```

Пробовал:

> sudo CHMOD 775 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php
>
> sudo chmod -R 0755 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php
>
> sudo chown nobody /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/upload.php
>
> Так же меня права для файла и папок everyone - read&write

Comment: Так же пробовал запускать xampp через терминал 
SUDO /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выставил права на саму папку xampp

> sudo CHMOD 775 /Applications/XAMPP/
>
> sudo chmod -R 0755 /Applications/XAMPP/
>
> sudo chown nobody /Applications/XAMPP/